# insert error in mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I am experiencing problems while inserting date type value in mysql using PDO

code snippet :

```
 $HOST = 'localhost';
 $DATABASE = 'db';
 $USERNAME = 'XXXXXX';
 $PASSWORD = 'XXXXXX';

 $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$HOST;dbname=$DATABASE;charset=utf8",$USERNAME,$PASSWORD);
 $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  

 $incomingdate  = date('Y-m-d', time());  // this echoes 2013-07-03
 $name = "XYZ";

 try {

  $stmt = $DBH->query('INSERT INTO tablename (date ,name ) VALUES (?, ?)');
  $stmt->execute(array($incomingdate, $name  ));
  $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
  echo $row_count.' rows selected';

     }
 catch(PDOException $e ){
    echo 'Error in executing query ...';
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Datatype at the mysql database side of date column is : *DATE*

Error : 
Below is the contents of PDOErrors.txt
**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031**

What is wrong with this query....earlier query ran smooth when i used mysql_* functions ...
so what is wrong with prepared statements ???
And also .... what  should be done if datatype is of *Timestamp type* and / or *datetime type*  at the mysql end

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks around `date` column name and use `->prepare` instead of `->query`

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename (`date` ,`name` ) VALUES (?, ?)');
```

Comment: Atleast say reason for downvoting?

Comment: Not my downvote but probably because `date` is not a reserved word in MySQL. Refer to the docs for a list of reserved words `MySQL permits some keywords [e.g date] to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. ` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @MrCode Thanks, I got it, previously most of people get error because of that.

Comment: Nobody never get an error from that. Your answer is wrong as usual.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `prepare()` for a prepared statement, not `query()`:

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename (date ,name ) VALUES (?, ?)');
```

`PDO::query()` can't have bound parameters, only a statement created through `PDO::prepare()` can.